# Call a function within a structure within a class

Tags: ios, swift

I have two files: ClassA.swift and ClassB.swift

```
class ClassA: NSObject {
    struct StructA {
        func talk(string: String) {
            println("I say: \(string)")
        }
    }
}


class ClassB: NSObject {
    func makeItTalk(string: String) {
        ClassA.StructA.talk("Hello") <--------------
    }
}
```

I get the following error message

> Type 'ClassA.StructA' does not conform to protocol 'StringLiteralConvertible'

Any idea why? Is it actually something than can be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing `StructA` in a static context, whereas you need an instance of it:

```
class ClassB: NSObject {
    func makeItTalk(string: String) {
        var myStruct = ClassA.StructA()
        myStruct.talk("Hello")
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if your goal is to access that method statically, just declare it as a static struct method:

```
static func talk(string: String) {
    println("I say: \(string)")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `func talk(string: String)`
to `static func talk(string: String)`

Answer (score 1):

You are using `talk` as `static` method, but it is declared as instance method. Change to:

```
class ClassA: NSObject {
    struct StructA {
        static func talk(string: String) {
            println("I say: \(string)")
        }
    }
}
```